# Issue using leaps() code

Tags: r, regression

In my case, the data consisted of 8 variables and 500 observations. When I used the `leaps()` code, instead of showing the $2^8 - 1$ submodels, the output showed only 10 models corresponding to those n, where $n \choose 2$ > 10. How can I get the entire output?

Comment: One of the arguments of the function `leaps` is `nbest` with a default `nbest=10`. Have you tried altering this argument? See [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/leaps/docs/leaps). However, I have the impression that you will not get all $2^8-1$ models anyway because `leaps` does not actually run all those regressions. If you ask for more than some 40 best models, it will start taking quite long.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the code worked.

Comment: Also, check out the function [regsubsets](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/leaps/docs/regsubsets), a wrapper for `leaps` which may be more user-friendly.

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).